# Viewing XmlTextwriter Content within debugger

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, memorystream, xmltextwriter

I am working on some pretty complex code that is writing to a memorystream using an XmlTextwriter. Is there a way in Visual Studio debug to see the content of the memorystream/XmlTextwriter as I am stepping through code.

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't be using `XmlTextWriter`. Use `XmlWriter` via `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy to get it from the `MemoryStream`:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray())
```

(That's assuming you've told it to use UTF-8; use `Encoding.Unicode` or whatever's appropriate if necessary.)

It doesn't make as much sense to ask the `XmlTextWriter` - it's just *writing* data, and probably doesn't know or care what it's already written. You *may* want to flush it, mind you.

Comment: Thanks Jon. You always help me out. BTW how long have you been programming?

Comment: @Robert: It depends on exactly what you mean... I wrote my first programs on a Spectrum when I was about 8, 27 years ago :)